# Add Vector Tiles (Mapbox Vector Tiles) to QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-tiles, mapbox-vector-tile

How to add this Vector Tile URL (Mapbox Vector Tiles) to QGIS?

[https://ogc-api.nrw.de/lika/v1/collections/flurstueck/tiles/WebMercatorQuad/{z}/{y}/{x}?f=mvt](https://ogc-api.nrw.de/lika/v1/collections/flurstueck/tiles/WebMercatorQuad/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D?f=mvt)

I tried `Layer` -> `Add Layer` -> `Add Vector Tile Layer`, there created a `New Generic Connection`, named it and posted the upper URL. There is no Style URL given. Then I clicked `OK` and `Add`. Now the new Layer appears under Layers but it seems not to be rendered. I tried to zoom in pretty much, but nothing is shown (in an area where there have to be items). Maybe someone can try to add this layer to QGIS and describe the way to do so.

As an alternative there is a "TileJSON" given under

https://ogc-api.nrw.de/lika/v1/collections/flurstueck/tiles/WebMercatorQuad?f=tilejson

I have no clue, how to handle with this JSON-File, but it should be possible to copy the FileJSON-URL to an application that supports TileJSON. Does QGIS support this kind of URL and how?